# Can a namespace start with a number in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

When declaring the following namespace:

```
<?php

namespace Example\3000;
```

I got this error:

```
Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '3000' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in [...]
```

So I wondered whether a namespace in PHP may start with a number?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it must not. It must start with a letter.

It took me a while to find this in a [comment on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php#104196).

To use numbers e.g. for versioning it is necessary to prepend letters, e.g. like in the following:

```
<?php

namespace Example\V_3000;
```

Comment: Mate, I would have just said "No".

Comment: Did You.. answered just after asking?

Answer (score 1):

Note: Special character cannot be used. The only special character I have found that works is the underscore (_). For example if you want a folder for version 3.0.01, then do the following:

```
    <?php
    namespace Example\v3_0_01;
```